# What does all these mean?

Tags: webgl

I am entirely new to the realm of graphics and I am finding it particularly hard with WebGL. I would like to know how to "plot" x,y,z given their screen coordinates...

Suppose say

```
x = 50, y = 0, z = 0,,
x = 50, y = 0, z = 600,,
....,,
x = 4900, y = -52, z = 0,,...
```

and there are certain indices like `2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 4,....`

and then, there is something called 4x4 transformation matrix like

```
-0.6,-0.6,0,0,,
 0.6,-0.6,0,0,,
 0,0,1,0,,
 1590,980,0,1...`
```

What am I supposed to do with all these - if I need to get the relevant shape...

Is it possible to explain with some sample data ?

Comment: Do you have a basic understanding of linear algebra? If not I would try a to get some. A very nice book is http://www.amazon.de/Practical-Linear-Algebra-Geometry-Toolbox/dp/1568812345

Comment: For Computer Graphcis you have to learn again the chapters you have forgotten in school maths: At least Vector arithmetic and Matrix operations.

Comment: @morpheus05 : no... I will start learning things anyway... thanks for the reference..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of details, and unfortunately you did not share what you know and what you don't.

Have a look at some good introductory tutorials:

http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-fundamentals/

http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217

Comment: Thanks. No I dont know anything about WebGL / any other graphics. I am pretty much new - just learning things since yesterday. I took upon a problem and these are the information that was there. Now I dont know what to do with all these information...

Comment: Try to follow Greggman's posts about WebGL on http://games.greggman.com/game/tag/webgl/. I'm sure you will get a good understanding of WebGL there.